# What is the purpose of having a wrapper class for JarFile in Spring-boot-loader?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

My question relates to [Spring-boot-loader v2.6.15](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.6.15/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar).

For the purposes of this question, I will refer to Spring's custom `JarFile` class as `CustomJarFile` to avoid confusion.

---

### Context

I am reusing some of the jar package code in spring-boot-loader. I noticed that they define their own [`CustomJarFile` implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.15/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.java) that (most relevant to this question) overrides the `close()` method like so:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (this.closed) {
        return;
    }
    super.close();
    if (this.type == JarFileType.DIRECT) {
        this.rootFile.close();
    }
    this.closed = true;
}
```

They also define a [`JarFileWrapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.15/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileWrapper.java) class that **does not** override the close method.

The custom [`JarUrlConnection#get()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.15/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.java#L266) method notably returns an instance with the wrapper rather than the jar itself like so:

```
static JarURLConnection get(URL url, JarFile jarFile) throws IOException {
    // some stuff here...
    return new JarURLConnection(url, jarFile.getWrapper(), jarEntryName); // JarFile here is the custom class
}
```

Testing the code without the wrapper class by returning a `JarUrlConnection` with the `CustomJarFile` itself rather than its wrapper results in a "zip file closed" exception.

This is reasonable given that when you call `close()` on the wrapper, it will call the `close()` method of the `ZipFile` class. However, if the `JarFile` itself is sent, it will call the `close()` method of the `JarFile` since it is overriden.

Notably, The JavaDoc of the wrapper class states:

> A wrapper used to create a copy of a {@link CustomJarFile} so that it can be safely closed without closing the original.

---

### Question

I do not quite understand the purpose of using a wrapper here. If the goal is to just avoid closing the `CustomJarFile`, wouldn't simply not overriding the `close()` method in `CustomJarFile` (allowing it to propogate to `ZipFile`) have the same effect as using a wrapper? It feels like we just added a redundant layer.

While debugging, I've noticed that the `close()` method of `CustomJarFile` is never called between startup and shutdown of the service which makes me further believe that the wrapper is pointless if you simply remove the overriden close method in `CustomJarFile`.

Answer (score 1):

##### Why does the wrapper exists and why doesn't it override `close()`?

Apparently, [this wrapper was introduced](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/aac367e9c5e40733421716f2edfb3522f3480119) to "Attempt to fix memory leak in JarFile class". The memory leak issue was caused by a change in java 11 that introduced `FinalizableResource` which made it so that [any JarFile implementation that override close() will end up with finalizer based cleanup](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22991#issuecomment-675202657).

Ultimately, too many JarFile instances are being created, especially given they [used to wrap the `JarFile` in a `JarFile`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/aac367e9c5e40733421716f2edfb3522f3480119#diff-4fb8fa007e8483410daf8be17b0b3c21ade3396eba622254f79c6060fef13a1eL269), without ever being cleaned by the garbage collector since `FinalizableResource` doesn't deference it.

The simplest way to tackle this was to create a wrapper class that doesn't override `close()` which would be created/returned instead of `JarFile`, essentially working around the problem.

##### Why was the `JarFile` wrapped in itself before the wrapper was added?

In the question I said the `close()` method in JarFile is never called which made sense since it was never returned. However, it seems `JarFile` is actually exposed through `JarURLConnection.getJarFile()` and therefore may get closed and [run you into trouble](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17796). I assume the exposure is intentional since that's not what was changed. My testing missed it, but the point here is that situations definitely exist where it *could* be called.

##### Java got rid of problematic code?

Well, apparently Java didn't like the change any more than Spring did and `FinalizableResource` [was removed](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/a655e6b52b3819092c0e874d95e39c124d681381#diff-b6128c3608aaf04e0802af64a2df5bb981e33bf873d41017df2c9ca4e187a545L847) in literally the first java 12 tag: `jdk-12-ga`. I currently use Java 17 and it still does not exist.

##### Is the wrapper still necessary?

Unclear... It may still be necessary for the same reason `JarFile` was wrapped in itself before. It may not since the language has changed a lot since. Either way, I've learned to be happy with the wrapper and coexist :)